# Correct php typehint for doctrine column type "decimal"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I use this column in one of my entities:

```
/**
 * @var float
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=20, scale=2)
 */
public $value;
```

According to the [Doctrine docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html), the `decimal` type is returned as a `string` to PHP, but I am using it as a `float`. Should I typehint it with `@var float` then, or is `@var string` correct?

Anyway, If I use this variable for arithmetic calcualtions, eg.

```
$object->value + $otherobject->value
```

am I risking to get undesired behaviour (like only adding the integer parts )?

Comment: The entity properties should be private or protected, not public. You can use getters and setters to access them.

Answer (score 4):

Generating an entity with the command line tools provided by Symfony 4, a field of type `decimal` can be generated like this:

```
New property name (press <return> to stop adding fields):
> percent

Field type (enter ? to see all types) [string]:
> decimal

Precision (total number of digits stored: 100.00 would be 5) [10]:
> 5

Scale (number of decimals to store: 100.00 would be 2) [0]:
> 4
```

This results into the following property and getter/setter methods:

```
<?php

// ...

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="decimal", precision=5, scale=4)
 */
private $percent;

public function getPercent()
{
    return $this->percent;
}

public function setPercent($percent): self
{
    $this->percent = $percent;

    return $this;
}
```

So per default Doctrine generates the getter/setter methods without type hinting.
The getter will return `string`, while the setter expects an argument of type `double` (which is just a synonym for `float`).
Therefore you couldn't do something like:

```
/**
 * @var float
 */
private $value;
```

Since the value will be returned as string you shouldn't do calculations like the one in your question, but take care for previous transformation.

EDIT:
An alternative to type hinting with `string` or `float` can be the external library [PHP decimal](http://php-decimal.io/#introduction).

You can [install](https://packagist.org/packages/php-decimal/php-decimal) it  with this command:

```
composer require php-decimal/php-decimal
```

Comment: One more reason to use string PHP type instead of float is how Unit of Work computes changeset. If you get objection from database, it will be stored as string, but as soon as you call setPercent() it will convert this value to float and even that the value would seem to be the same, actually it will be updated. In case you wonder why Doctrine updates your entity event if there the value "seems" to be the same.

Comment: Why did you say that the setter expects a double?

Comment: @PhoneixS I answered this more than 4 years ago. I haven't used Symfony 4 for a while. I have forgotten the details.

Answer (score -3):

I would do like this :

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="float", precision=20, scale=2)
 */
public $value;
```

Comment: That's wrong answer. Column of type *float* has no attributes *precision* and *scale*.

Comment: You should at least add some explanation to your answer about **why** you would do this